# Выбор структуры базы данных

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Есть сайт, на который нужно написать систему уведомлений, о новых подписках, о новых сообщениях, о новых постах и др., всего пока пять видов уведомлений. Сейчас на сайте доступны только уведомления о количестве непрочитанных сообщений, эта цифра берется из таблицы user, вместе с другими данными типа email, nickname и др. Я собрался вводить другие уведомления и встал вопрос, как будь лучше для пользователя и для системы построить базу данных:

- Вариант 1. В таблице `user` завести поле `notice`, принимаемые значения 0 или 1, если для этого юзера есть уведомления значит нужно сделать запрос в таблицу `notice`, откуда уже забирать для этого юзера все уведомления.
- Вариант 2. В таблице `user` завести поля для всех видов уведомлений, `notice_msg`, `notice_comment` и т.д., и выводить в шаблон без дополнительных запросв точное количество уведомления для каждого вида оных.

Помогите понять, как будет лучше сделать?

Answer (score 2):

```
table:
-user
--id (pk)
--first_name
--last_name

table:
-message_notice
--id (pk)
--user_id (fk)
--notice_text

table:
comment_notice
--id (pk)
--user_id (fk)
--notice_text

или одну таблицу для notice

table:
notice
--id (pk)
--type*
--user_id (fk)
--notice_text
etc
```

Comment: Поддерживаю вариант с одной таблицей для уведомлений. Тут, скорее всего, стоит сделать дополнительную таблицу с типами уведомлений. Тогда вместо type будет type_id (fk), а в таблице типов будут поля id и type. Впрочем, можно и без этой вспомогательной таблицы обойтись.

Comment: Я планировал в начале сделать одну таблицу, но потом решил все-таки спросить совета.

Comment: Если в зависимости от notice меняются/добавляются какие либо атрибуты (у сущностей), то имеет смысл сделать отдельные таблицы для каждого notice.